# Building a function $f$ such that $\| f - f_n \|_{L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Consider an arbitrary open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ and an arbitrary element $1 \leqslant p < \infty$. Moreover, let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)$ denote a convergent sequence in $L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)$, for every $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$. In other words, for each $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$ there exists a function $f_{x,r} \in L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)$ such that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\| f_{x,r} - f_n \|_{L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)} = 0. $$

My goal is, *if possible*, to build a function $f$ such that

$$  \tag{1} f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Omega) \quad \text{ and }\quad  \lim_{n \to \infty}\| f - f_n \|_{L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)} = 0, $$

for every $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$.

**My attempt.** Clearly, to prove the R.H.S condition of $(1)$, it is sufficient to establish that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \| f - f_n \|_{L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)} \leqslant \lim_{n \to \infty} \| f_{x,r} - f_n \|_{L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)}, $$

for every $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$. Furthermore, simple calculations yield

$$ \| f - f_n \|_{L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)} \leqslant \| f - f_{x,r} \|_{L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)} + \| f_{x,r}- f_n \|_{L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)}, $$

for every $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in \Omega, r > 0$. This inequality turns out to not provide a viable choice since the functions $f_{x,r}$ are not necessarily equal for different values of $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$. Hence, I am looking for an alternative approach to prove this result.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Take a partition of unity $\{\rho_j\}_{j\in J}$ subordinate to the open cover of $\Omega$ by balls $B(x,r)\subseteq\Omega$.  For $x,r$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq\Omega$ let $J_{x,r}=\{j\in J\colon \text{supp}\rho_j\subseteq B(x,r)\}$.  Take $f=\sum_{x,r}\sum_{j\in J_{x,r}} \rho_j f_{x,r}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ChadK . I wasn't familiar with some of the concepts in your comment, so it took me a while to read it carefully. You start by noticing that there exists an open cover of $\Omega$ that consists of balls $B(x,r) \subset \Omega$ and you implicity denote this open cover by $\{B_j\}_{j \in J}$. Moreover, you consider a partition of unity $\{ \rho_j \}_{j \in J}$ subordinate to this same open cover. Afterwards, for every $x,r$ s.t. $B(x,r) \subset  \Omega$ you define $$ J_{x,r} := \{ j \in J \colon \operatorname{supp} \rho_j \subset B(x,r) \} $$

Comment: @ChadK and you conclude by telling me to take $f = \sum_{x,r} \sum_{j \in J_{x,r}} \rho_j f_{x,r}$. I have a question about this formulation of $f$: what kind of pairs $(x,r)$ are we considering? Because if we make no restriction on these pairs, we might end up with $(x,r)$ such that $B(x,r) \not\subset \Omega$, so that $J_{x,r}$ makes no sense, correct?

Comment: Actually, I wrote it wrong because the way I wrote it the sum may contain duplicates of the $\rho_j$.  What you need is for each $j\in J$ to *choose* a pair $(x_j,r_j)$ such that $\text{supp}\rho_j\subseteq B(x_j,r_j)\subseteq\Omega$.  Then let $f=\sum_{j\in J} \rho_j f_{x_j,r_j}$.  This makes sure to avoid duplicates.  The supports of the $\rho_j$ cover all of $\Omega$.

Comment: @ChadK I am assuming that when you write $J$ you mean a subset of $\Omega \times \mathbb R^+$ which is formed by some pairs $(x,r)$ such that $B(x,r) \subset \Omega$ and $\bigcup_{(x,r) \in J} B(x,r) = \Omega$. Moreover, since $\{B_j\}_{j \in J}$ is a open cover of $\Omega$, there exists a partition of unity $\{ \rho_j \}_{j \in J}$ such that $\text{ supp } \rho_j \subset B_j$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity). Hence, it's clear that for each $j \in J$ it  follows that $\text{supp } \rho_j \subset B_j = B(x_j,r_j) \subset \Omega$, for some $x_j \in \Omega$ and $r_j > 0$.

Comment: @ChadK With this in mind, now your idea is to consider $f = \sum_{j \in J} \rho_j f_{x_j,r_j}$. Now how do we proceed to prove $\| f - f_n \|_{L^p(B(x,r) \cap \Omega)} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$? This isn't obvious to me

Comment: 1) Show that for all $x\in\Omega$ there is some $s>0$ such that $\|f-f_n\|_p\to 0$ on $B(x,s)\subseteq\Omega$.  Use the properties of partition of unity for this.  2) Show that for all $x,r$ such that $B(x,r)\cap\Omega\ne\emptyset$, $f=f_{x,r}$ almost everywhere on $B(x,r)\cap\Omega$.  Use that every open cover of an open set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ has a countable subcover.

Comment: @ChadK I can't follow point $1)$. I will denote the $p$-norm on $B(x,s) \cap \Omega$ simply by $p$. For every $x \in \Omega$ and $s > 0$ we have that $$ \| f - f_n \|_p^p = \int_{B(x,s) \cap \Omega} |f(y) - f_n(y)|^p \, dy = $$ $$  = \int_{B(x,s) \cap \Omega} \Big| \sum_{j \in J} \rho_j(y) f_{x_j,r_j}(y) - f_n(y)\Big|^p \, dy = \int_{B(x,s) \cap \Omega} \Big| \sum_{j \in J} f_{x_j,r_j}(y) - f_n(y) \Big|^p \, dy. $$ Now I don't know what choice of $s > 0$ yields the desired result. I have thought about picking $s$ such that $(x,s) \in J$ but I think that this is not always a possible choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is much simpler than you thought. The key is that the following caution in your OP

> This inequality turns out to not provide a viable choice since the functions $f_{x,r}$ are not necessarily equal for different values of $x\in \Omega$ and $r>0$.

**is almost unnecessary.**

The reason is that $L^p(X)$ for a measure space $X$ is a normed space, so limit in $L^p$ is unique. That is, two limit functions are equal almost everywhere.

Therefore, if $B(x_1, r_1)\cap B(x_2,r_2)\neq \emptyset$, then the limits
$$
f_{x_1,r_1}=f_{x_2,r_2} \text{ a.e. in }B(x_1, r_1)\cap B(x_2,r_2),
$$
since $f_n\to f_{x_1,r_1}$ and $f_n\to f_{x_2,r_2}$ in $L^p(B(x_1, r_1)\cap B(x_2,r_2))$. Therefore we have a function
$$
F_2(y):=\begin{cases}
f_{x_1,r_1}(y) & y\in B(x_1,r_1)\\
f_{x_2,r_2}(y) & y\in B(x_2,r_2)\backslash B(x_1,r_1)
\end{cases}
$$
defined on $B(x_1, r_1)\cup B(x_2,r_2)$. Furthermore, $F_2=f_{x_2,r_2}$ a.e. on $B(x_2,r_2)$.

Now since ${\mathbb R}^n$ is second countable, there exist a countable family of $\{B(x_i,r_i)\}$ such that
$$
\Omega = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B(x_i, r_i).
$$
Let $E_k=\bigcup_{i=1}^k B(x_i, r_i)$.
By induction, we can build a sequence of functions $F_k$ on $E_k$, using $F_{k-1}$ on $E_{k-1}$ and $f_{x_k,r_k}$ on $B(x_k,r_k)\backslash E_{k-1}$, just as how we build $F_2$ above.

Eventually the sequence $F_k$ totally extend each other, and defines a function $F$ on $\Omega$ by
$$
F(y) := F_k(y) \quad\text{if }y\in E_k.
$$

Furthermore, by its construction and the uniqueness of $L^p$ limit,
$$
F=f_{x_i,r_i} \text{ a.e. on }B(x_i,r_i).
$$
Then $F$ is the limit $f$ you were looking for.

Now we show that
$$
F\in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Omega).
$$
Let $K\subset \Omega$ be a compact subset. Then by the definition of compactness, there exists finitely many $B_j=B(x_{i_j}, r_{i_j}), j=1,\dots, N$ such that $K\subset \bigcup B_j$. Then
$$
\int_K |F|^p \leq \sum_{j=1}^N \int_{B_j} |F|^j = \sum_{j=1}^N \int_{B(x_{i_j}, r_{i_j})} |f_{x_{i_j},r_{i_j}}|^p <\infty.
$$

The last thing to do is to consider a general $B(x, r)$. But since $B(x, r)\cap \Omega\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B(x_i,r_i)$, by the uniqueness of $L^p$-limit, we see that the limit here
$$
f_{x, r} = F \text{ a. e. on }B(x, r)\cap \Omega.
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f_n-F\|_{B(x,r)\cap \Omega}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f_n-f_{x,r}\|_{B(x,r)\cap \Omega} = 0,\quad \forall x\in \Omega, r>0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some questions, and I should start by the beggining. It seems like you start by considering arbitrary elements $x_1,x_2 \in \Omega$, $r_1,r_2 > 0$ and state that if $B(x_1,r_1) \cap B(x_2,r_2) \neq \emptyset$, we immediately have that $$ f_{x_1,r_1} = f_{x_2,r_2} \quad \text{ almost everywhere on } B(x_1,r_1) \cap B(x_2,r_2). $$ I believe that here you're assuming that $f_n \to f_{x_1,r_1}$ on $B(x_1,r_1)$ and $f_n \to f_{x_2,r_2}$ on $B(x_2,r_2)$, correct? If so, what is the necessity of the assumption $B(x_1,r_1) \cap B(x_2,r_2) \neq \emptyset$ ?

Comment: You are right. If the intersection is empty, then the statement is vacuously true, so logically I don't need the condition.

Comment: There is still one thing about  this first thought that you presented about the two balls $B(x_1,r_1)$ and $B(x_2,r_2)$ that is confusing me. I understood everything that you wrote about this but it seems like you're assuming that $f_n \to f_{x_1,r_1}$ on $B(x_1,r_1)$ and $f_n \to f_{x_2,r_2}$ on $B(x_2,r_2)$ and I don't think this is necessarily true based on my assumptions. What we can guarantee based on the assumptions is that $f_n \to f_{x_1,r_1}$ on $B(x_1,r_1) \cap \Omega$ and $f_n \to f_{x_2,r_2}$ on $B(x_2,r_2) \cap \Omega$.

Comment: Sure, replace the balls by  their intersections with $\Omega$. In the later constructions, the balls are contained in $\Omega$, so no change is needed for them.

Comment: After this analysis on the two balls, you begin by stating "Now since $\mathbb R^n$ is second countable, there exists a countable family of $\{B(x_i,r_i)\}$" such that $\Omega = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B(x_i,r_i)$". Intuitively, I can understand that there exists a family $\{ B(x_i,r_i) \}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ such that $x_i \in \Omega, r_i > 0$ for every $i \in \mathbb N$ and $\Omega = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B(x_i,r_i)$, but I don't see how this follows from the definition of second countable. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: A basis for a topology is a way to build up the topology. In particular, every open set is a union of some basis elements. The topology for a metric space is defined by having the basis of metric balls. A space is called second countable if it has a countable basis. ${\mathbb R}^n$ is second countable because we can take a countable basis using balls centered at points with all rational coordinates and having rational radii. Therefore every open set in ${\mathbb R}^n$ is a countable union of such balls.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification once again. I still have (at least) one more question, if that's okay. I have been trying to formally prove that $ F = f_{x_i,r_i} $ almost everywhere on $B(x_i,r_i)$, for every $i \in \mathbb N$ but I am having a hard time doing so. My approach was by induction, as I believe it should be, but I am having trouble with the induction step. I believe it should be similar to the initial discussion about $f_{x_1,r_1}$ and $f_{x_2,r_2}$ but I haven't been able to figure it out. Perhaps you can add more details about this claim ?

Comment: Sure, so we want to show that $F_{k-1} = f_{x_k, r_k}$ a.e. on $B(x_k, r_k)\cap E_{k-1}$. Noting that $E_{k-1}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1} B(x_i, r_i)$, and by induction, $F_{k-1}=f_{x_i, r_i}$ a.e. on $B(x_i, r_i)$. Now in $L^p(B(x_r, r_i)\cap B(x_k, r_k))$, $f_n\to f_{x_i, r_i}$ and $f_n\to f_{x_k, r_k}$, so $f_{x_k, r_k} = f_{x_i, r_i}$ a.e., and so $f_{x_k,r_k}=F$ a.e. on $B(x_r, r_i)\cap B(x_k, r_k)$. Since a finite union of null set is null, $f_{x_k, r_k}=F$ a.e. on $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1} B(x_i, r_k)\cap B(x_k, r_k) = E_{k-1}\cap B(x_k, r_k)$.

Comment: Also, I think this is a good question, because you need to use it to show $F=f_{x, r}$ a.e. in $B(x, r)\cap \Omega$ in the last step. There, you need to use $f_{x, r}=f_{x_i, r_i}=F$ a.e. on $B(x, r)\cap B(x_i, r_i)$. Since $B(x, r)\cap \Omega = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B(x, r)\cap B(x_i, r_i)$, and countable union of null sets is null, we see $f_{x, r}=F$ a.e. on $B(x, r)\cap \Omega $.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understood your proof which guarantees that $$ F = f_{x_k,r_k} \text{ almost everywhere on } B(x_k,r_k), \quad \forall k \in \mathbb N.  $$ On the other hand, I am having a hard time understanding your argument to prove that $F = f_{x,r}$ on $B(x,r) \cap \Omega$. You seem to start by assuming that $F = f_{x_i,r_i}$ a.e. on $B(x_i,r_i)$ for every $i \in \mathbb N$ (this is true due to the precedent proof) and you also assume that $F = f_{x,r}$ a.e. on $B(x,r)$. How do you guarantee this last assertion? It seems to me this isn't necessarily true.

Comment: I am just using $f_{x, r}=f_{x_i, r_i}$ a.e. on $B(x, r)\cap B(x_i, r_i)$ since $f_n$ approaches both in $L^p$, together with as you say, $F=f_{x_i, r_i}$ a.e. already established, to say $f_{x, r}=F$ a.e. on $B(x, r)\cap B(x_i, r_i)$. (Again, being equal a.e. is an equivalence relation.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, once again. Just to finish, I have a few more questions: firstly, I was able to formally prove that $F_k = f_{x,r}$ almost everywhere on $B(x,r) \cap \Omega$, for every $k \in \mathbb N$. Now I am trying to extend this to $F$ but it's causing me some confusion.  Intuitevely it should be direct since $F$ is defined to be some $F_k$ and $F_k = f_{x,r}$ almost everywhere on $B(x,r) \cap \Omega$ but if we pick different points $y$ the natural number $k$ doesn't necessarily remain the same. Perhaps you can elucidade me on how you think about this?

Comment: Secondly, can you add details on how you concluded that $F \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$? This is not direct for me. The definition I am working it is the following one: $$ L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Omega) := \left\{ f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb R \text{ Lebesgue measurable } \, \colon \int_K |f(y)|^p \, dy < \infty, \text{ for every compact set } K \subset \Omega \right\}. $$

Comment: Actually the way we concretely defined $F_k$ made it true that $F_k=F_l$ in $E_k$ for $l\geq k$. So the non uniqueness of $k$ should not be a problem, since they are the same functions when both are defined. About the local $L^p$ property, I have edited the post.

Comment: I think I understand almost everything now. Just one more thing: how do you obtain from the definition of compactness that there exists finitely many $B_j = ( B(x_{i_{j}}, r_{i_{j}}), j= 1, \dots, N$ such that $K \subset \bigcup B_j$ ?

Comment: Since $\Omega=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B(x_i, r_i)$, and $K\subset \Omega$, so $\{ B(x_i, r_i)\}$ is an open covering of $K$. Since $K$ is compact, this open covering has a finite subcovering, hence the $B_j, j=1,\dots,N$ such that $K\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^N B_j$.